# Postfix relay and store

Tags: postfix, mx-record

So, I am setting up a backup mail server.

I got it relaying messages (saving them to queue and then, as soon as primary's up, deliver them to primary).
It took following two lines:

```
relay_domains = $mydestination domain.tld
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks
                               check_relay_domains
```

However. I want a secondary not only to relay messages, but also to store them to local mailboxes (provided, the local mailboxes with needed names exist), so I could access them in case of emergency via, say, roundcube webmail.

How do I make Postfix both relay and receive messages at the same time?

Comment: An MX20 relay is not best practice for postfix redundancy, its better to go with 2 equivalent MX10. If you are able to read german, I can suggest you to read this article from Heinlein: https://www.heinlein-support.de/upload/mk4/3-06_Best-Practice-fuer-stressfreie-Mailserver.pdf

Comment: Hell yes am I able to read German. Thanks for the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution can be to have the relay server has a fake domain and then using `recipient_bcc_maps` BCC all the messages to local addresses with the fake domain.

Add to main.cf the following:

```
recipient_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc_maps
```

and also add `fake.domain.com` to the end of `mydestination = ...`, this way this server will get the all of the `user@fake.domain.com` e-mails (if the user exists).

In `/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc_maps` put:

```
user@your.domain.com user@fake.domain.com
```

than run `postmap recipient_bcc_maps`

This way to every message to `user@your.domain.com` a BCC will be added to `user@fake.domain.com` so the message will be stored locally.

Comment: I think, it might be something that would work. Could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: Can I apply some sort of wildcard, so that I'd not have to edit files every time users are added?

Comment: Maybe by using prce based recipient_bcc_maps. Put `recipient_bcc_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc_maps` in `main.cf`, and `/^(.*@your\.domain\.com)/   ${1}@fake.domain.com` in it. But haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Looks like we're out of luck on this one, sadly. Or it needs to be addressed further. Anyway, thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.